# Verify that an item was actually changed, not just opened and closed

Tags: workflow

I have been asked to create a workflow that will notify a certain individual whenever someone other than him either creates a new item or modifies an existing item.  I have run into a problem in which the workflow runs even if someone only opens the item, does not make any changes and closes the item.  Apparently, SharePoint includes this as a "modified" event.  I need to make sure that SharePoint differentiates between this event and an actual modification in order to start my workflow or in order to make a decision within the workflow so the correct message is sent, i.e. item has been modified.  I should add that I do not have access to the server so I cannot use Visual Studio to create my solution.  It needs to be entirely out-of-the-box and done thru the workflow or list.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an item updating event receiver, and you need visual studio, period.  I guess you could do it in sp designer, but I always avoid sp designer.

http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/event-receivers-walkthrough4/

remember there is adding event added, updating and updated.

LOL: By the way, you dont need access to the server to develop, you have to have your local environment, create a visual studio solution, create a event receiver, build, package, and send the wsp for the IT team to install it using powershell

Answer (score 0):

This will likely be a fair amount of work using a workflow but since you can't use visual studio [this tutorial](http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.com/2007/10/sharepoint-designer-workflows-how-to.html) will show you how to compare the field values to their previous value in a workflow. Then you will need find the changed fields (maybe store them in a variable) and send them to your user.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use a workflow for this? Have you tried using the standard alerts that come with SharePoint? You can sign him up for an alert or have him sign himself up for an alert whenever any item is changed and email him immediately. It seems this is exactly the sort of situation that alerts were made for.